The $n$th statement in a list of $100$ statements is "Exactly $n$ of the statements in this list are false". What can we conclude?

The $n$th statement in a list of $100$ statements is "Exactly $n$ of the statements in this list are false".
For this problem, based on the screenshotted answer, would the part I highlighted be sufficient to show that exactly 99 of them are false and the 99th statement is true?
My reasoning as of now:
So we have either (0 of the statements are false) to (100 of them being false). Exactly 0 of them being false wouldn't make sense since we'd have all of them true but they'd contradict each other (mutually exclusive).
Exactly 100 of them being false wouldn't work since that would make the 100th statement (which is the same statement we just assumed true) also false, hence contradiction.
So we have $1 \leq$ (# false) $\leq 99$. Since all these statements are mutually exclusive (btw that just means that only 1 of them can be true, right?) Exactly 1 of the statements must be true, hence 99 are false, making 99th statement the only true one and rest false.
Kindly please let me know if this reasoning is correct.

no idea. Write out  in detail, instead of 100 statements, exactly 2 statements. Then exactly 3 statements.

@WillJagy Wait sorry I'm confused, what do you mean?

I'd say the person probably wrote down stuff without concern of the truth values.  It's not impossible to say "This sentence is false" after all.

I mean only that one may consider  a much smaller problem  with fewer statements, so small that  one could draw up lists, draw diagrams, and completely work out the problem  then. The process is likely to show you the concepts that matter for the original problem.

If you only consider the highlighted part, then you are overlooking the theoretical possibility that all 100 mutually exclusive statements could still be false. You need the paragraph preceding the highlighted part to realize that that would make the 100th statement true, a contradiction.

Thank's so much for the answer! I just edited my answer to give my own reasoning. Kindly is that correct way of reasoning it out?

Also, does mutually exclusive just mean that only one of them can be true?

Your answser makes perfect sense to me. Mutually exclusive literally means that at most one of every pair can be true, but this is easily equivalent to the statement that at most one of the the whole set can be true. It still leaves the possibility for zero true statements, i.e., all of them could be false.

But why does it leave possibility that 0 of them are true? Is it because all possibilities are really from 0 to 100 being false rather than just 1 to 100 being false... like we're trying to consider all the cases and do process of elimination from there? Is that what you're saying?

Of course there is no actual possibility for 0 of them to be true, it's just that the phrase "mutually exclusive" alone leaves that possibility open.

Why do you say "Of course there is no actual possibility for 0 of them to be true"?

@BobMarley Because if $~0~$ of them are true, then you have exactly $~100~$ false statements, which makes statement-100 true.  This yields a contradiction.  In fact, the analysis in Lieven's answer makes this exact point.

@Lieven Hey sorry I just came back to this question and realized I wasn't following/reading your reasoning carefully before. So you're saying that when the statements are "mutually exclusive", that means "at most 1 of them is true" and hence either exactly 0 or exactly 1 is true. We can see that 0 being true is contradictory, so exactly 1 is true/99 statements false, hence the 99th statement is only true...

@Lieven Assuming that was you're reasoning, I feel I'm confused by the definition of "mutually exclusive" and think I've been using it wrong. When I would use it I'd assume "n mutually exclusive claims" means "exactly 1 of the n claims is true" instead of "at most 1 of the n claims is true". Kindly which is the correct definition?

"To exclude" means to ensure someone or something cannot get in; for a logical proposition, that means to ensure it cannot be true. If a proposition excludes another proposition, it means that it makes sure that the other proposition cannot be true. That does not say anything about the truth of the first proposition, i.e., they could still both be false. All we know is that they cannot both be true.
